# how to effeciantly format json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex

I am trying to format json data in the most efficient way. I need to format 2 different keys in a object. both are strings
I made a fiddle with the json
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxaknman/)

```
var json = [
{
    "Id": 1,
    "ReportId": 1,
    "ReportName": "HBO: {MSA}"
    "QueueDate": "2015-08-25T17:16:54.233",
    "Parameters": "<xml><CBSA>Abilene, TX</CBSA><CBSASK>3</CBSASK><CBSAID>1203</CBSAID><CBSACode>10180</CBSACode><MonthNumber>6</MonthNumber><Month>June</Month><Year>2015</Year><FromDate>06/01/2014</FromDate><ToDate>06/01/2015</ToDate></xml>"
},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "ReportId": 2,
    "ReportName": "HBO:{Marvin}"
    "QueueDate": "2015-08-25T17:20:50.463",
    "Parameters": "<xml><CBSA>Abilene, TX</CBSA><CBSASK>3</CBSASK><CBSAID>1203</CBSAID><CBSACode>10180</CBSACode><MonthNumber>6</MonthNumber><Month>June</Month><Year>2015</Year><FromDate>06/01/2014</FromDate><ToDate>06/01/2015</ToDate></xml>"
},
{
    "Id": 3,
    "ReportId": 2,
    "ReportName": "HBO:{Marvin}"
    "QueueDate": "2015-08-25T17:23:58.377",
    "Parameters": "<xml><CBSA>Abilene, TX</CBSA><CBSASK>3</CBSASK><CBSAID>1203</CBSAID><CBSACode>10180</CBSACode><MonthNumber>6</MonthNumber><Month>June</Month><Year>2015</Year><FromDate>06/01/2014</FromDate><ToDate>06/01/2015</ToDate></xml>"
}
```

]

I need to end up with:

```
ReportName: 'MSA',
Parameters: 'Abilene, Tx'
```

Comment: Why put XML in JSON in the first place ? Plus, I don't get what you're up to. Are you trying to format JSON, or to parse JSON (or XML) ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or just want the solution?

Comment: yes ive tried some things but nothing worked out. it wasnt very "elegant"

Comment: @X.L.Ant I am working with what i have.. this is a json object. I need to parse the string with the xml. I need the value in between <CBSA></CBSA>

Comment: Embedding XML in JSON isn't very "elegant" either, but here we are... have you tried a regex, and did that mostly work but had corner cases someone can suggest workarounds for?  Can you at least count on the XML being well formed and constrained so a REGEX solution, while brittle, is at least tractible?

Comment: yes, REGEX will be good, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.parseXML()` to convert the xml string  to an xml document object, then wrap that in `$()` to use jQuery traverse methods on it

```
$.each(json, function (_, item) {
    var $xml = $($.parseXML(item.Parameters));
    var cbsa = $xml.find('CBSA').text();    
    $('body').append($('<p>').text(cbsa));
});
```

Reference: [parseXML() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1c7mwmgr/)**</kbd>